# Do I need to create a database in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Do I need to create a new database using MySQL, or is a database already created, and all I have to do is fill in the info?

The given database info is in the config file, under the database.php file and is shown below.  Is this all that is needed to create a table?

```
    'MySQL' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Or do I need to create the database in the terminal, as shown below?

mysql CREATE DATABASE MySampleDB;

mysql CREATE USER db_user WITH PASSWORD "mypassword";

Comment: You need to create.

Comment: DB and Laravel project are different tools, that you should create and connect yourself.

Comment: After I build and connect the server, do I fill in the info in the laravel file?

Comment: If you've stumbled on this simple question, I would recommend to start with the basic things, because otherwise it will be really hard to understand what is what.

Comment: Don't touch laravel files. Do touch `.env` :)

Comment: Check out laracasts.com there are free tutorials on the basics of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is learn more about migrations. Short answer to your question is Yes! Thats what laravels main functionality is. You use the Eloquent Model Helpers, and the Controllers.

I would suggest taking a look at this video tutorial on how to effectively use Laravel 5.2 (Yes this is outdate because at the time of writing this we are on version 5.4, however the same concepts are there.)

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx

DevMarketer is amazing and explains the concepts behind why things are done and he doesn't just give you the code.

Migrations, Models, Views, Controllers, etc.... All covered in that video series.